# Regex for validating UTF-8 contains only "normal" characters

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, unicode

In my project, users can register with a publicly viewable nickname.  I would like to allow that name to contain characters from any script (arabic, latin, cyrillic, japanese, etc) but prevent control characters, punctuation, and non-alphabetic characters such as ✇ or ✈.

I've found a lot of examples for filtering alphanumeric characters from various individual scripts, but I don't want to have to spend days digging through encoding tables to try and allow every script through manually.

Any recommendations?

Comment: You mean you want a simple solution without many `[\somecode-\someothercode]` or rather that you don't want to try to define such a solution yourself ?

Comment: BTW the state of unicode in javascript regular expressions is very sad...

Comment: A simple solution without a massive list of codes would be great if it exists, but I also suspected that might be impossible, and doing it myself seems exceptionally error-prone and time consuming.  I'm hoping there is an existing solution somewhere that I was just unable to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, when you want to deal with Unicode in regular expressions, the usual solution is to give up.

The next most usual solution is to use [xregexp](http://xregexp.com/) which does happen to [have the classes you seem to need](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/README.md#unicode) :

```
var unicodeWord = XRegExp('^\\p{L}+$');
unicodeWord.test('Русский'); // -> true
unicodeWord.test('日本語'); // -> true
unicodeWord.test('العربية'); // -> true
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used \p{Latin} before in Perl to select all Latin characters. There is a whole list of options about half-way down on this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html.

It seems that this could carry over to Javascript since it uses XRegExp.

Edit 2: OR - make up a list of NON-allowed characters to check against - then \p{common} would be a starting point.

Edit: apparently my memory of doing this is from many eons ago. I cannot get it to work with my current Perl build (which is a special case). So - it may be completely off-base.

Comment: That's definitely a step in the right direction.  I hadn't found that list before, which makes doing it myself a tiny bit less daunting.